# How do I change the default directory for Windows Terminal for WSL?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image: This is the current opening directory]

I want wsl to open in "Desktop" folder by default. (C:\Users\dharm\Desktop)
The Desktop folder is inside the "dharm" folder in which its currently opening.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shell is Bash and that it is reading `.bash_profile`, add

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

to the end of that file. (If it doesn't exist, but you have `.bashrc`, try adding it there. If neither file exists, create `.bash_profile` in your home directory. If you have a different shell, consult its documentation.)

Take care to use a proper editor - Bash will display errors if you add DOS line feeds to the file.

My prediction is that you will want to remove this hack once you learn the basics of the system. Perhaps add a guard to only do it when `SHLVL` is one:

```
[[ $SHLVL -eq 1 ]] && cd ~/Desktop
```

so it only happens when you start your first shell.

(Not familiar with WSL; maybe experiment to find whether `SHLVL` is actually at some other value when you have just started the system.)